# MySQL SELECT using WHERE & BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I've serveral databases with the same structure:

dsid, tag, timestamp, value

Timestamp is in unixtime, and I can select data to plot like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.`dsid` ,' - ', t.`dsid` - 1) AS `DSIDs`
 , t.`value` - (SELECT `value`
                FROM `MY-DB` 
                WHERE `dsid` = t.`dsid` - 1 * 20) AS `kWh`,
                tag, dsid, value,
                FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%y-%d-%m %H:%i')
FROM `MY-DB` t limit 10000;
```

But I want to select it based on a "where date between" structure, so I can choose a month or week... Or even better "last" week, month, year (full calendar year or just the last 12 month).

But if I try like that it fails:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.`dsid` ,' - ', t.`dsid` - 1) AS `DSIDs`
 , t.`value` - (SELECT `value`
                FROM `MY-DB` 
                WHERE `dsid` = t.`dsid` - 1 * 20) AS `kWh`,
                tag, dsid, value, (FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%y-%d-%m %H:%i') WHERE 'timestamp' BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('16-27-03 23:45')) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('16-25-02 00:00')
FROM `MY-DB` t limit 10000;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: So what did you find googling converting from a date & number of time periods to a date? Google my comments re googling many phrasings/versions of a question. Also, what does "fails" mean? Please act on [mcve]. PS You may not want SQL `between` because it is inclusive.

Comment: I've found several different version and uses of the documented examples, but non of them worked for me, or I used them the wrong way. Fails meens this: [Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 'timestamp' BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('16-27-03 23:45')) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('' at line 5

Comment: There is no select to match the final where in the 2nd code block. Note that the froms & any joins & any where are typically indented the same amount. See my edit to your froms. In the future cut stuff out until you don't get the error in order to localize it. Per **[mcve]** which you are still missing here. PS Edit your question, don't clarify in comments.

Comment: THX for helping wrap my head around this, just got it in 5 additional minute's!

Comment: Hi. Please post your solution as an answer and then accept it after the minimal wait, to show you have found a solution. Click on the 'edited' link to get your unformatted text. Also then click on 'roll back' of the previous version. Note that typically if like here an answer turns out to be that there was a typo or simple syntax problem the question will get voted closed (locked from further answers) by later readers of sufficient reputation. Remember for next time--**MCVE**.

Comment: THX for keeping the site clean ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was wrong is that I placed the WHERE & BETWEEN in the wrong place, this is how it works for me:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.`dsid` ,' - ', t.`dsid` - 1) AS `DSIDs` , t.`value` - (SELECT `value`
            FROM `MYDB` 
            WHERE `dsid` = t.`dsid` - 1 * 20) AS `kWh`,
            tag, dsid, value,
            FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%y-%m-%d %H:%i') as time
FROM `MYDB` t
WHERE timestamp
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('16-08-01') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('16-08-31 23:59:59')
```

Might not be the most efficient way to do it..